# divide a region into north and south based on a set of latitude longitude coordinates

Tags: r

I have a set of latitude and longitude coordinates for a specific region. I would like to divide this region into north and south using one of the longitude/latitude coordinates. for example, I have

```
    latitude    longitude
    3.898556   -39.037852
    3.768441   -39.049052
    3.868112   -39.035689
    3.898005   -39.037213
    3.885487   -39.037852
```

I would like to select the coordinates (3.885487   -39.037852) as a reference such that all latitudes falling above this will be north while those coordinates below this will be south. any help on how to do this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?  How to compare numbers in `R`?  How to apply a comparison to multiple data points?  What have you tried so far?  (This is not a homework completion service.)

Comment: There have been many wars started by dividing regions into North and South.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()`, so if the coordinates are in a dataframe "df" and you want to add a column with information on North/South:

```
df$var_name <- ifelse(df$latitude>3.885487, "North", "South")
```

This will assign "South" to the reference latitude, if you in fact want it to be "North" you can use `>=`